# Edit applicationhost.config with appcmd.exe at different location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express, appcmd

Can I use *appcmde.exe* to edit *applicationhost.config* at different location? For example: Visual Studio 2015 creates *applicationhost.config* at *.vs\config* directory. I could manually edit this file but i would like to prefer to use *appcmd.exe*.

Comment: Jexus Manager can be an even quicker way, http://Jexus.lextudio.com

Comment: This is not really answer answer to my question but can I choose in Jexus Manager location of applicationhost.config to be edited?

Comment: you can add individual config files as a new server to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `apphostconfig` to specify a different `applicationhost.config` file.

For example:

```
appcmd list site "mysite" /config /apphostconfig:"%userprofile%\projects\myproject\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jexus Manager](http://jexus.lextudio.com) gives an IIS Manager alike experience, but of course you can use IIS Express appcmd,

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme

Starting from IIS 8 Express it supports the /AppHostConfig switch as the readme fie indicates.